# Modifiy response in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Below my Laravel controller code

```
public function templateValueData($template_id)
{
    $parent = TemplateMetadataValue::where('template_id', $template_id)->get();

    return $parent;
}
```

Here, the output of the method above;

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "name": "Category 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 63,
    "parent_id": 11,
    "name": "Category 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 73,
    "parent_id": 63,
    "name": "Category 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 77,
    "parent_id": 11,
    "name": "Category 5"
  },
  {
    "id": 83,
    "parent_id": 77,
    "name": "Category 8"
  }
]
```

Now I want to format this response base on the value of `parent_id`.

The condition is: when `parent_id` is equal to `id`, then the `parent_id` is considered as children of the `id`.

Please note that both `parent_id` and `id` are stored as incremental values.

I want to alter and return the response as below;

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "name": "Category 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 63,
        "parent_id": 11,
        "name": "Category 2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 73,
            "parent_id": 63,
            "name": "Category 3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 77,
        "parent_id": 11,
        "name": "Category 5",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 83,
            "parent_id": 77,
            "name": "Category 8"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for achieve your response.

```
public function templateValueData($template_id)
{
    $parents = TemplateMetadataValue::where('template_id', $template_id)->get();
    $arr = $this->xyz($parents);
    return $arr;
}
```

Function for achieve response.

```
function xyz($parents,$parent_id = 0){
    $res = [];
    foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
        if ( $parent[ "parent_id"] == $parent_id ){
            $children = $this->xyz($parents, $parent[ "id"]);
            if ($children) {
                 $parent[ "children"] = $children;
            } 
            $res[]=$parent;
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your relation on your controller:

```
public function templateValueData($template_id)
{
    $parent = TemplateMetadataValue::where('template_id',$template_id)->with('children')->get();

    return $parent;
}
```

Also you can use method injection on your controller methods, so you can use this code:

```
public function templateValueData(TemplateMetadataValue $template)
{
    return $template->load('children')->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you slightly modify your `TemplateMetadataValue` model then you could achieve the desired result.

```
class TemplateMetadataValue extends Model {

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Call it with `children` method.

```
$parent = TemplateMetadataValue::with('children')->get();
```

Rest of the login you can apply here with your query builder.

Comment: This will give results like
`
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "name": "Category 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 63,
        "parent_id": 11,
        "name": "Category 2",
      },
      {
        "id": 77,
        "parent_id": 11,
        "name": "Category 5",
      }
    ]
  }
]
`